# regex to disallow space at begining and end and allow only one space between characters

Tags: javascript

How can I reject leading space and ending space and allow only one space between characters in JavaScript ?

I tried many patterns, here is last one:

```
^[^-\s][a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]*$
```

But this doesn't allow space at all.

I am using `[a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]` because I just want to allow English characters.

Also  I cannot use trim or replace. I am binding keypress to input field on html and check for the pattern and if `regex.test(e.key)` is false I disable the event.

Comment: What do you mean by "disable"? Do you mean remove? Or not match? Do you mean a **total** of one space between characters, or at most one space between **any** two characters? Please show more examples of test inputs and the results. Do you require a regexp which matches on valid input, or is it acceptable to match on invalid input and not match on valid input? BTW the name of the language is "JavaScript". Also, please spell-check your question title, and capitalize the first letter of sentences (and the word "I*) as we do in proper English.

Comment: will match() on every keyup resolve your case? You can not predict is this space in input the last one or user will change it to letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This validates the given String as you requested:

```js
var wrong = "  hello,   my dear   friend  ";
var right = "hello, my dear frind"

function validate(s){
  var validateRegEx = new RegExp(/^\s+|\s\s+|\s+$/g);
  return !s.match(validateRegEx);
}

console.log("Validation of '" + wrong + "': " + validate(wrong));
console.log("Validation of '" + right + "': " + validate(right));
```

Comment: i cant use trim or replace , i am binding keypress to inut and check for the pattern and if regex.test(e.key) is false i diable the event .

Comment: @user6599525 please update your question, this information changes much :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a regexp which matches valid input, rather than matching invalid input as in other answers, then:

```
/^\S(?!.*  )\S$/
```

`\S` is a non-space. The middle part is a negative lookahead ensuring there are not two spaces anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You just try to remove leading and trailing space? Try something like that:

```
str.match(/^\s+.*\s+$/g,'');
```

**UPD:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').on('change keyup', function(e) {

    var str = $(e.target).val();
    var disallowed = str.match(/^\s+.*|.*\s+$/g);
    
    if (disallowed != null) {

      $('button').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {

      $('button').prop('disabled',false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<button>add</button>
```

Comment: i cant use trim or replace , i am binding keypress to inut and check for the pattern and if regex.test(e.key) is false i diable the event

Answer (score 0):

`/^\s+|\s{2,}|\s+$/g` is what you looking for. Plus, it's not `e.key` what you want to validate, it's `this.value`.

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
document.getElementById("test").onkeyup = function() {
  var str = this.value;
  if (/^\s+|\s{2,}|\s+$/.test(str))
    this.className = "not-valid";
  else
    this.className = "";
}
```

```css
.not-valid{
  background-color: #FAA;
}

span{
  color: red;
  display: none;
}

.not-valid+span{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<input id="test" /><span> not valid</span>
```

Comment: i cant use trim or replace , i am binding keypress to inut and check for the pattern and if regex.test(e.key) is false i diable the event

Comment: @user6599525 check the new answer.